# Error Submitting CN1 Android Build

Tags: codenameone

I am receiving the following error when attempting to send/submit my CN1 project for an Android build. I'm using Eclipse, and it builds locally and runs in the simulator.

build-for-android-device:

BUILD FAILED
C:\MyData\Projects\coden1_playground\MyAssistant\build.xml:468: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask.execute(CodeNameOneBuildTask.java:273)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:527)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:473)
    at codenameoneplugin.actions.SendBuild$1.run(SendBuild.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Total time: 9 seconds

Any assistance would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you delete `icon.png` or remove the file you point to as an icon?

Did you replace it with a non-image file?

The icon for the app must be a 512x512 png format image.

Comment: Thanks Shai, that was it. The file was there, and I don't recall ever changing it. It's like it was corrupt. I simply replaced it and was able to submit the build. Unfortunately, it then gave an error on build. This was late last night, so I haven't even had a chance to research it much. I'll try to take a look at it tonight.

Comment: Updated local.properties
No project name specified, using project folder name 'google-play-services_lib'.
If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
Added file /tmp/build8101888440777042023xxx/MyAssistant/dependency/google-play-services_lib/build.xml
Added file /tmp/build8101888440777042023xxx/MyAssistant/dependency/google-play-services_lib/proguard-project.txt
Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 21308
org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: It sounds like something was seriously corrupted in your project somehow, I suggest you look in the codenameone_settings.properties and see that everything is correct there.

Comment: Thanks Shai, I'll take a look at it. I may even just go ahead and create a new project.